# URl not able to open in Titanium WebView

Tags: rss, feed

While i am opening this [link](http://www.chicagowolves.com/news?format=feed&type=rss) .It's giving me an below error.I did parsing and able to get  all things.But client want to open in browser like webpage.Please tell me what should i do?

> Error loading: http://www.chicagowolves.com/news?format=feed&type=rss,
>   Error: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load
>   interrupted" UserInfo=0x9946670
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.chicagowolves.com/news?format=feed&type=rss,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.chicagowolves.com/news?format=feed&type=rss,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted}

Comment: Please let me know if any thing missing or not able to get the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* a web page, it is RSS, therefore you can not load it as a web page, as your client wants.

This is an RSS feed which is an XML based format, and therefore needs to be parsed, read and displayed by an RSS reader (or something of that nature) the web view is *not* the way to do this, no matter what your client thinks.

Here is a open source [RSS reader sample application on GitHub](https://github.com/kwhinnery/iPad-RSS) for Titanium. If your client truly wants to see the raw rss, then you should download the file using the an HTTPClient [(heres the doc)](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient) and display it as text in a TextField.

Comment: Thanks,i knew that it's a RSS even i parsed it and added in the App but he can open this url on his Mac browser.That's why  asked whether it can be done means any other way.Thanks for reply!!